# How to overlay several images in Matlab?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, overlay

I have the images A, B and C. How to overlay these images to result in D using Matlab? I have at least 50 images to make it. Thanks.

[Please, see images here.](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B5AOSYBy_josdEprb0VaRk15aTQ)

Download images:

A: `https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B5AOSYBy_josQ3R3Y29VVFJVUHc`

B: `https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B5AOSYBy_josTVIwWUN1a085T0U`

C: `https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B5AOSYBy_josLVRwQ3JNYmJUUFk`

D: `https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B5AOSYBy_josd09TTFE2VDJIMzQ`

Comment: Do you have only images, or do you have the underlying data set to generate the image of each molecule (using `surf` for example)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**To fade the images together:**

Well since images in matlab are just matrices, you can add them together.

```
D = A + B + C
```

Of course if the images don't have the same dimensions, you will have to crop all the images to the dimensions of the smallest one.

The more you apply this principle, the larger the pixel values are going to get. It might be beneficial to display the images with `imshow(D, [])`, where the empty matrix argument tells `imshow` to scale the pixel values to the actual minimum and maximum values contained in `D`.

**To replace changed parts of original image:**

Create a function `combine(a,b)`.

Pseudocode:

```
# create empty answer matrix
c = zeros(width(a), height(a))

# compare each pixel in a to each pixel in b
for x in 1..width
    for y in 1..height
        p1 = a(x,y)
        p2 = b(x,y)

        if (p1 != p2)
            c(x,y) = p2
        else
            c(x,y) = p1
        end
    end
end
```

Use this `combine(a,b)` function like so:

```
D = combine(combine(A,B),C)
```

or in a loop:

```
D = combine(images(1), images(2));
for i = 3:numImages
    D = combine(D, images(i));
end
```

Comment: Please, see images and expected result in posted links above.

Comment: I apologize, that definitely wasn't what you were looking for.  I've kept my original explanation for anybody who might want to see it and I've added what I believe to be a reasonable solution to your problem. Keep in mind that the answer returned by my solution is very much dependent on the order in which you specify A, B, and C.

Comment: If you don't want the answer to be dependent on the order of arguments, then you need to come up with some function that determines which pixel to keep in the event that `p1 != p2`.

Comment: Also, if you want to apply that one function to 50 images, you can do it in a loop (see above).

Comment: I have been scouring all of SO and M Central for this answer and about a day later, the easiest and most sensible answer is given here. If you were physically present here, I would kiss you!

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the example, it seems to me that the operation requested is a trivial case of "[alpha compositing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing)" in the specified order.

Something like this should work - don't have matlab handy right now, so this is untested, but it should be correct or almost so.

```
function abc = composite(a, b, c)
  m = size(a,1); n = size(a,2);
  abc = zeros(m, n, 3);
  for i=1:3
    % Vectorize the i-th channel of a, add it to the accumulator.
    ai = a(:,:,i); 
    acc = ai(:);
    % Vectorize the i-th channel of b, replace its nonzero pixels in the accumulator
    bi = b(:,:,i); 
    bi = bi(:);
    z = (bi ~= 0);
    acc(z) = bi(z);
    % Likewise for c
    ci = c(:,:,i);
    ci = ci(:);
    z = (ci ~= 0);
    acc(z) = ci(z);
    % Place the result in the i-th channel of abc
    abc(:,:,i) = reshape(acc, m, n);
 end
```